# gpio-admin: could not flush data

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am attempting to access gpio pin on my Raspberry pi using Node.js + the pi-gpio module but I get the following error:

```
"Error when trying to open pin 11" "gpio-admin: could not flush data to /sys/class/gpio/ex[prt: device or resource busy"
```

I've checked that directory, with pin 11 exported or unexported I still get the same error.

In-case it's the code I've attempted to convert from Python to node, here is the code for review:

```
    var gpio = require("pi-gpio");

function motor1(){
    gpio.write(7, 1, function(err){
    //if err
    console.log("sent 1");
    });
}

function motor2(){
    gpio.write(11, 1, function(err){
    console.log("sent...");
    });
}
gpio.open(7);
gpio.open(11);

motor1();
motor2();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you still got it open from a previous session? I had the same issue when I hadn't closed it before,

Trying running the following at the end of your program, after your motor1 and 2 calls:

```
gpio.close(pin);
```

Because they are already open you may still see the error first time you run it, so check on the 2nd run